# Building WPEWebkit on a Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I'm following the [instructions](https://github.com/WebPlatformForEmbedded/buildroot) on building WPEWebkit on a Pi 3.

But it doesn't work, I've tried [this](http://silicone.homelinux.org/2017/03/05/raspberry-pi-3-as-desktop-computer/) as well.

I've updated my `gcc` to `6.3`. I'm using Raspbian Jessie w/ Pixel (4.4).

Here is the error I get:

```
/home/pi/Desktop/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/ccache /usr/bin/gcc -std=gnu99 -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_divrem_1 -I/home/pi/Desktop/buildroot/output/host/usr/include -O2 -I/home/pi/Desktop/buildroot/output/host/usr/include -Wa,--noexecstack tmp-divrem_1.s -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/divrem_1.o
tmp-divrem_1.s: Assembler messages:
tmp-divrem_1.s:129: Error: selected processor does not support `mls r1,r4,r8,r11' in ARM mode
tmp-divrem_1.s:145: Error: selected processor does not support `mls r1,r4,r8,r11' in ARM mode
tmp-divrem_1.s:158: Error: selected processor does not support `mls r1,r4,r8,r11' in ARM mode
tmp-divrem_1.s:175: Error: selected processor does not support `mls r1,r4,r3,r8' in ARM mode
tmp-divrem_1.s:209: Error: selected processor does not support `mls r11,r4,r12,r3' in ARM mode
Makefile:768: recipe for target 'divrem_1.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [divrem_1.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: managed to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that I'm building buildroot/wpewebkit on rpi3. I should be building the image on my development machine.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.